# How to Filter Several Dataframes Using Two Master Dataframes with Purrr's Pmap and Dplyr's Semi_Join

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

```
 library(tidyverse)
```

Using the sample datasets below (three for 201603, and three for 201602), I'm attempting to use two master datasets to filter several other datasets by using tidyverse tools such as `dplyr::semi_join`, `purrr::map2`, and `purrr::pmap`. I would like the output to be a list of the filtered data. However, I've become stuck while trying to use `pmap()` to accomplish all this in one set of code so I can output one list of all the filtered data.

This example is a bit complicated, so I'll try to break it down. First, I used this code to put the two "201603" datasets that need to be filtered into a list called "List1". I then used `purrr::map` to change the Id column name so that I can use a semi_join after.

```
List1<-list(One201603,Two201603)%>%
map(~rename(.x,"Id"="ID"))
```

Next, I used `purrr::map2` to iterate over List1, and a list of MainData201603, which is the master dataset for 201603 that is being used to filter the other two datasets. This outputs a list, and then I change the list element names with `purrr::set_names`.

```
Df<-map2(List1,list(MainData201603),semi_join,by="Id")%>%
set_names(c("One201603","Two201603"))
```

Everything works up to here, but now I have another master dataset called "MainData201602", as well as two other datasets that need to be filtered, "One201602", and "Two201602". I could simply follow the same steps as above, but I don't want to repeat code and I feel there's a more elegant way to do it all in one step using purrr tools such as pmap(). I'm thinking something like the code below, which doesn't work. I tried several other variations of pmap and lists, but couldn't figure it out. Help would be appreciated!

```
List2<-list(One201602,Two201602)%>%
map(~rename(.x,"Id"="ID"))

 Df<-pmap(list(List1,list(KPI201603)),list(List2,list(KPI201602)),semi_join,by="Id")%>%
map(~set_names(.x,c("One201603","Two201603","One201602","Two201602")))



Id<-c(6666,3333,1111,9999,8888,5555,2222,4444)
Animal<-c("Rabbit", "Moose", "Dog", "Cat", "Squirrel", "Raccoon", "Fish", "Elephant")
MainData201603<-data_frame(Id,Animal)

ID<-c(6666,3333,4545,6767,3322,1111,8888,8876,9990,1234,7775,3445)
Person<-c("Chris","Yuki","Mike","Darren","Katrina","Camilla","Dreanna","Nathan","Aisha","Sra","Pierre","Luigi")
One201603<-data_frame(ID,Person)

ID<-c(6666,8888,4453,1243,1111,5567,4543,8898,4444,7665,7889,5554)
Person<-c("Mr.K","Ms.S","Mr.P","Mr.B","Mrs.N","Mrs.W","Mr.D","Ms.A","Ms.M","Mr.X","Mrs.Z","Ms.T")
Two201603<-data_frame(ID,Person) 

MainData201602<-MainData201603

One201602<-One201603

Two201602<-Two201603
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. The idea is to create `List1` and `List2` with proper names. And then create a list called `target`, containing `List1` and `List2`, and a list called `master`, containing `list(MainData201603)` and `list(MainData201602)`. After that, we can use `map2` to apply the `map2` function you developed to `target` and `master`.

```
List1 <- list(One201603,Two201603)%>%
  map(~rename(.x,"Id"="ID")) %>%
  set_names(c("One201603","Two201603"))

List2 <- list(One201602,Two201602)%>%
  map(~rename(.x,"Id"="ID")) %>%
  set_names(c("One201602","Two201602"))

target <- list(List1, List2)
master <- list(list(MainData201603), list(MainData201602))

map2(target, master, ~map2(.x, .y, semi_join, by = "Id"))
[[1]]
[[1]]$One201603
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Id Person 
  <dbl> <chr>  
1  6666 Chris  
2  3333 Yuki   
3  1111 Camilla
4  8888 Dreanna

[[1]]$Two201603
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Id Person
  <dbl> <chr> 
1  6666 Mr.K  
2  8888 Ms.S  
3  1111 Mrs.N 
4  4444 Ms.M  


[[2]]
[[2]]$One201602
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Id Person 
  <dbl> <chr>  
1  6666 Chris  
2  3333 Yuki   
3  1111 Camilla
4  8888 Dreanna

[[2]]$Two201602
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Id Person
  <dbl> <chr> 
1  6666 Mr.K  
2  8888 Ms.S  
3  1111 Mrs.N 
4  4444 Ms.M
```